# css media print, display page number

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got page which contents refs to another pages

```
<div class="page">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page1">
</div>
```

how to display page number when printing

—> page 1. 3

—> page 2. 5

Answer (score 0):

can use title tag for that

```
<title>page 1</title>
<div class="page">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page1">
</div>`
```